# Calculate 2 values in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem when I want to calculate two different values in Access. I want to count them up so I have a total number. The problem is when one value isn't available because It is NULL. When this happens it gives me a value of #Size! .

Here's a screenshot of my problem.

[image: problem]

When I have both values available there's no problem.
[image: Succeed]

Here's is the code I use to calculate te field.

```
=Nz([UC7_subForm_Artikelen].[Report]![sumTotalArtikelen])+Nz([UC7_subForm_Taken].[Report]![sumTotalTaken])
```

So what I want is if one value is missing it just gives a 0 as return value.

Would be great if you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your equation you are asking if the wrong thing is null

```
=Nz([UC7_subForm_Artikelen].[Report]![sumTotalArtikelen]) <~~ is [sumTotalArtikelen] null?
+Nz([UC7_subForm_Taken].[Report]![sumTotalTaken])    <~~ is [sumTotalTaken] null?
```

But, really not only are they not null, the controls don't exist at all. That subreport has no records so the report is not rendered at all. You need to check one level higher. Either check that `[UC7_subForm_Taken].[Report]`/`[UC7_subForm_Artikelen].[Report]` is not null or check that the Master field with links the parent report to the child report is not null/makes no link.